# Configure multiple Active Directory paths in WSO2 IS user store

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are facing a problem connecting WSO2-Identity Server 5.1.0 with multiples paths in Active Directory in a single userstore.

We have the following configuration in Active Directory:

```
 |- DC=org
    |- DC=company
       |- DC=users
          |- OU=Department1
             |- CN=User1
             |- CN=User2
          |- OU=Department2
             |- CN=User3
```

I have created an Active Directory based UserStore that gets the users from Department1 correctly (User1 and User2). Now I want to get also the users from Department2 without creating another UserStore.

I tried the following filter in "User Search Base" field without succees:

- (&(OU=Department1)(OU=Department2)),DC=users,DC=company,DC=org
- ((|(OU=Department1)(OU=Department2)),DC=users,DC=company,DC=org)
- (&(OU=Department1,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org)      (OU=Department2,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org))
- (|(OU=Department1,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org)(OU=Department2,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org))
- OU=(&(Department1)(Department2)),DC=users,DC=company,DC=org
- OU=Department1,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org;OU=Department2,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org
- ((OU=Department1,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org)(OU=Department2,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org))

Also I try to get all the user in "User Search Base" and make a filter for those users:

- "User Search Base": DC=users,DC=company,DC=org
- "User DN Pattern": (&(CN={0},OU=Department1,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org)(CN={0},OU=Department2,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org))(|(CN={0},OU=Department1,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org)(CN={0},OU=Department2,DC=users,DC=company,DC=org))CN={0},(|(OU=Department1)(OU=Department2)),DC=users,DC=company,DC=org

Is there any way to configure this properly without in just one single userStore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a hash sign (#) as the separator.

```
ou=Department1,dc=users,dc=company,dc=org#ou=Department2,dc=users,dc=company,dc=org
```

Comment: We've tested this and it appears to work, but I cannot find any official documentation on this. Can you please identify the source of this information?